# cannot initialize spring context due to "Error creating bean with name.." error

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, rhel, selinux

My spring application is running on jboss 4.2.3, when I start the application server deployment of My application failed. 
I have already run this application on some other computer. what seems to be diffrent is that;

**When I list the files there is a dot preceding the permission columns, however on the former 
computer I dont see any dot in the permission columns.**

the bean definition is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">



        <!-- Service -->
        <bean id="campaignCatalogService" class="com.commonutil.utils.CometCommonManager" factory-method="getCampaignCatalogService"/>

        <bean id="campaignPropertyService" class="com.commonutil.utils.CometCommonManager" factory-method="getCampaignPropertyService"/>

        <bean id="comboBoxOptionService" class="com.commonutil.utils.CometCommonManager" factory-method="getComboBoxOptionService"/>

        <bean id="workspaceService" class="com.commonutil.utils.CometCommonManager" factory-method="getWorkspaceService"/>

        <bean id="campaignGroupPropertyService" class="com.commonutil.utils.CometCommonManager" factory-method="getCampaignGroupPropertyService"/>

        <bean id="campaignDefinitionService" class="com.commonutil.utils.CometCommonManager" factory-method="getCampaignDefinitionService"/>
```

the error log is as follows;

```
05-27@13:57 26 ERROR (ContextLoader.java:215)     - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'campaignDefinitionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-core.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3856)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4361)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5312)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy46.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy10.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:694)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1325)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegateFactory.createDelegate(ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegateFactory.java:40)
at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld.resolveDelegate(ReflectionWorld.java:111)
at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:363)
at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:258)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDeclaringType(ResolvedType.java:1336)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.WithinPointcut.isWithinType(WithinPointcut.java:50)
at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.WithinPointcut.fastMatch(WithinPointcut.java:67)
at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.couldMatchJoinPointsInType(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:234)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:253)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:287)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:113)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:66)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:345)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:309)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:361)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
... 149 more
05-27@13:57 26 ERROR (Discovery.java:410)     - failed sending discovery request java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.log4j.Category.isEnabledFor(Category.java:749)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.isTraceEnabled(Log4JLogger.java:333)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.down(TP.java:1167)
at org.jgroups.protocols.PING.sendMcastDiscoveryRequest(PING.java:278)
at org.jgroups.protocols.PING.sendGetMembersRequest(PING.java:259)
at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery$PingSenderTask$1.run(Discovery.java:406)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: When showing bean initialization errors, you need to show the beans.

Comment: I don t think that I have any problems with the bean definition, because it runs on some other machine. but I have added it. I think there is a security issue but I am not sure.

Comment: I think it is about SELinux. Does anyone know how should change my application to be compatible with SELinux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my Problem;
My source code is compiled with "1.6.0_18-b07", however the runtime environment is "1.6.0_45"
In general "java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)" error is about the java version conflict.

Answer (score 0):

StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is unlikely to be an exception of Spring Context. Possibly you have a constructor or post-construct method that is causing this exception. Please re-chech these methods or post the class code and let us check it.

Comment: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown from `org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebAppClassLoader.findClass` and I am sure I dont have any problems with spring context, beacuase I runs on other machines.

Comment: Ok. The real problem is related to Category.isEnabledFor line. Since you are insisting on not sending the real bean code, we may assume your logj configuration file could not be found. Please check your log4j configuration against your server

Answer (score 0):

Real Error:
"@ 05-27 13:57 ERROR 26 (Discovery.java: 410) - failed sending discovery request java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.log4j.Category.isEnabledFor (Category.java: 749) "

Bean is OK